# Need to probe r8169 after booting

Tags: 16.04, networking, ethernet, realtek

I am running 16.04 LTS x64. Since kernel 4.4.0, I must always issue the command `sudo modprobe r8169` after I boot, otherwise my ethernet connection does not work. If I check under network connections, an ethernet connection is listed, but if I click on the drop down menu in the system tray to see what connections are available, my ethernet connection is not listed.

If I run `sudo lshw` after boot, but before I probe the module, it tells me that the networkcard is "UNCLAIMED".

Update 1:

The output of `dkms status; grep r8169 /etc/modprobe.d/*` is as follows, and is identical before and after probing the module to get the ethernet connection working:

```
virtualbox, 5.0.18, 4.4.0-22-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 5.0.18, 4.4.9-040409-generic, x86_64: installed
/etc/modprobe.d/r8168-dkms.conf:# map the specific PCI IDs instead of blacklisting the whole r8169 module
/etc/modprobe.d/r8168-dkms.conf:# to blacklist the whole r8169 module
/etc/modprobe.d/r8168-dkms.conf:#blacklist r8169
```

How can I go about solving this issue? I would like to not have to probe the module on boot manually.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `dkms status; grep r8169 /etc/modprobe.d/*` terminal command.

Comment: information added!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have blacklisted the `r8169` module by installing `r8168-dkms`.

This can be fixed by

```
sudo apt-get purge r8168-dkms
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/r8168-dkms.conf
```

The second command may give `no file found` error, but it is OK.

Comment: `r8168-dkms` was not installed (likely had it installed in the past though), however removing it's configuration file did the trick. Thanks!